# calculate the number of uncommon words in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I have quite a large dataframe (2000+ entries) with a column for text. I want to calculate the amount of 'rare' words per each column. I think I have it mostly worked out, but at the last line
`final = [(len([w for w in df['text_cleaned'][idx] if w not in most_common])) for idx, w in enumerate(df)]` doesn't seem to be iterating over the entire dataframe, instead the output is only for the first two columns so I can't add that list back into my dataframe with `df['count']=final`.

Also, I am concerned about processing times, so I am wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

```
!pip install clean-text

import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
import pandas as pd
import string
from collections import Counter
from cleantext.sklearn import CleanTransformer
import string

# Sample data here
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['text']=['Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. A peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked. If Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. Where’s the peck of pickled peppers Peter Piper picked?',
            'Betty Botter bought some butter But she said the butter’s bitter If I put it in my batter, it will make my batter bitter But a bit of better butter will make my batter better So ‘twas better Betty Botter bought a bit of better butter', 
            'How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?. He would chuck, he would, as much as he could, and chuck as much wood. As a woodchuck would if a woodchuck could chuck wood',
           'Susie works in a shoeshine shop. Where she shines she sits, and where she sits she shines']

#--
# Convert strings to list
df['text_cleaned'] = [[i] for i in df['text']]

# Clean text for each row in dataframe
cleaner = CleanTransformer(no_punct=True, lower=True) # defining parameteres of the cleaner
full_text_clean = [cleaner.transform(element) for element in df['text_cleaned']]
df['text_cleaned']=full_text_clean

# Tokenize each row in dataframe
text_clean_string = [' '.join(list_element) for list_element in df['text_cleaned']]
Token = [nltk.word_tokenize(token_words) for token_words in text_clean_string]
df['text_cleaned']=Token

# ----
# create a list of all the words in the dataframe, to calculate the high frequency words accross the entier sample
full_text = [element for element in df['text']] # create a list
cleaner = CleanTransformer(no_punct=True, lower=True) # clean the list
full_text_clean = cleaner.transform(full_text)
Words_s = ' '.join(full_text_clean) # convert the list to a string
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(Words_s) # tokenize
dictionary = Counter(Words_s.split()).most_common(10) # dictionary of most 10 occuring words and their frequency
most_common = [x for x, y in dictionary]  # create a list of the top occuring words

# Compare the lists 
final = [(len([w for w in df['text_cleaned'][idx] if w not in most_common])) for idx, w in enumerate(df)]
```

Comment: To begin with,i may not be appropriate enough to answer to your question,but i would like to ask you what you set as "uncommon word",the one with frequency rate under a certain number or the words not in most_common list?
Because you calculate the top 10 most viewed words...

Comment: so I was thinking that 'uncommon words' would be words not in the most common list. And the most common list would be populated with the top 10 most frequently occurring words. You mentioned 'top 10 most viewed words' did I calculate the most frequent words wrong?

Comment: No,you calculated them correctly.So you should change your last command to->"final = [(len([w for w in df['text_cleaned'][idx] if w not in most_common])) for idx, w in enumerate(df["text_cleaned"])]  ,because if you leave it as df "idx" will take values [0,1] and not [0,1,2,3] as we want...That should count uncommon words from all rows of "text_cleaned" not only [0,1]

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness I wanted to post what I ended up doing. @Panagiotis Papastathis brought up a good point about the 'most_common words', in that I was specifying the top 10 words, but I was not taking into account their frequency. I eneded up replacing

```
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(Words_s) # tokenize
dictionary = Counter(Words_s.split()).most_common(10) # dictionary of most 10 occuring words and their frequency
most_common = [x for x, y in dictionary]  # create a list of the top occuring words
```

with

```
dictionary = Counter(Words_s.split()).most_common() # dictionary 
most_common = [x for x, y in dictionary if y >= 4 ]  # take into account frequency when filtering
```

which I think accounts for the problem (also removing the line where I tokenize the words)

And as @Panagiotis Papastathis pointed up the last line was changed to

```
final = [(len([w for w in df['text_cleaned'][idx] if w not in most_common])) for idx, w in enumerate(df["text_cleaned"])]
df['count']=final
```

so all together

```
from cleantext.sklearn import CleanTransformer
import string

# Convert strings to list
df['text_cleaned'] = [[i] for i in df['text']]

# Clean text for each row in dataframe
cleaner = CleanTransformer(no_punct=True, lower=True) # defining parameteres of the cleaner
full_text_clean = [cleaner.transform(element) for element in df['text_cleaned']]
df['text_cleaned']=full_text_clean

# Tokenize each row in dataframe
text_clean_string = [' '.join(list_element) for list_element in df['text_cleaned']]
Token = [nltk.word_tokenize(token_words) for token_words in text_clean_string]
df['text_cleaned']=Token

# ----
# create a list of all the words in the dataframe, to calculate the high frequency words accross the entier sample
full_text = [element for element in df['text']] # create a list
cleaner = CleanTransformer(no_punct=True, lower=True) # clean the list
full_text_clean = cleaner.transform(full_text)
Words_s = ' '.join(full_text_clean) # convert the list to a string
dictionary = Counter(Words_s.split()).most_common() # dictionary 
most_common = [x for x, y in dictionary if y >= 4 ]  

# Compare the lists 
final = [(len([w for w in df['text_cleaned'][idx] if w not in most_common])) for idx, w in enumerate(df["text_cleaned"])]
df['uncommon_words'] = final
```